# Transforming xml structure to nested concept structure part of Dita Application, need a solution to wrap conbody within the same level using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, dita

I want to wrap up the conbody within the same level of concept, which is not happening ref given in current output. It important to wrap the conbody within the same level of concept, which is a valid Dita structure with respect to DTD. Need help to format the structure reference given in expected output.

Second request, There is a content after r4 and r5, which is not in proper hierarchy reference given in xml input, I want to put the content in concept schema wrapping the content inside conbody, which is a valid Dita structure moreover structure should be created wrt hierarchy, for example if the content is after r4 then new concept mapping should be done at the r4 level etc... Reference given in expected output.

Please help on both the above request.

**XML Structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml sieinfotype="bulletin-sb">
  <frontm>
    <prolog>
      <refgrp>364</refgrp>
      <title id="NODE2">Door</title>
      <model>Test</model>
      <date month="9" year="09" />
    </prolog>
  </frontm>
  <body>
    <design id="NODE11">
      <r3 id="NODE37">
        <rtit id="NODE38">Door</rtit>
        <r4 id="ALLM">
          <rtit id="NODE14">General</rtit>
          <p>
            <hp2>Test:</hp2>
          </p>
          <list style="random">
            <li id="NODE15">Test li.</li>
            <li id="NODE16">Test</li>
          </list>
          <note>Failure
          </note>
        </r4>
        <p>Para after r4</p>
        <note>Para after r4</note>
        <r4 id="PROT">
          <rtit id="NODE17">Protocol</rtit>
          <p>Test</p>
          <note>Test note</note>
          <r5 id="NODE19">
            <rtit id="NODE20">General information</rtit>
            <note>Test note.</note>
          </r5>
          <p>Para after r5</p>
          <note>Para after r5</note>
        </r4>
      </r3>
    </design>
  </body>
</xml>
```

**XSL code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
   
    <xsl:template match="design">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
                <xsl:value-of select="'urn:ptc:names:arbortext:dita:xsd:techinfo.xsd'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xml/body/design//r3">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::rtit">
                <title>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*|text()"/>    
                </title>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
                <conbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
                </conbody>  
           
            
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xml/body/design//r4">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::rtit">
                <title>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*|text()"/>    
                </title>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <conbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
            </conbody>
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xml/body/design//r5">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::rtit">
                <title>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*|text()"/>    
                </title>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <conbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
            </conbody>
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xml/body/design//r6">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::rtit">
                <title>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*|text()"/>    
                </title>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <conbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
            </conbody>
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xml/body/design//r7">
        <concept>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::rtit">
                <title>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*|text()"/>    
                </title>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <conbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
            </conbody>
        </concept>           
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="rtit">
                 
    </xsl:template>    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <frontm>
    <prolog>
      <refgrp>364</refgrp>
      <title id="NODE2">Door</title>
      <model>test</model>
      <date month="9" year="09" />
    </prolog>
    <preface>
    </preface>
  </frontm>
  <body>
    <concept xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:ptc:names:arbortext:dita:xsd:techinfo.xsd"
      id="NODE11">
      <concept id="NODE37">
        <title id="NODE38">Door</title>
        <conbody>
          <concept id="ALLM">
            <title id="NODE14">General</title>
            <conbody id="ALLM">
              <p>
                <hp2>test:</hp2>
              </p>
              <list style="random">
                <li id="NODE15">TestLI.</li>
                <li id="NODE16">test.</li>
              </list>
              <note>test</note>
            </conbody>
          </concept>
          <p>Para after r4</p>
          <note>Para after r4</note>
          <concept id="PROT">
            <title id="NODE17">Protocol</title>
            <conbody id="PROT">
              <p>Test</p>
              <note>Test note</note>
              <concept id="NODE19">
                <title id="NODE20">General information</title>
                <conbody id="NODE19">
                  <note>Test note.</note>
                </conbody>
              </concept>
              <p>Para after r5</p>
              <note>Para after r5</note>
            </conbody>
          </concept>
        </conbody>
      </concept>
    </concept>
  </body>
</xml>
```

**Expected output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<concept xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:ptc:names:arbortext:dita:xsd:techinfo.xsd"
  id="NODE11">
  <title id="NODE2">Door</title>
  <shortdesc></shortdesc>
  <prolog>
    <critdates>
      <revised modified="09-9" />
    </critdates>
  </prolog>
  <concept id="NODE37">
    <title id="NODE38">Door</title>
    <conbody group="364">
    </conbody>
    <concept id="ALLM">
      <title id="NODE14">General</title>
      <conbody id="ALLM">
        <p>
          <hp2>Test:</hp2>
        </p>
        <li id="NODE15">Test.</li>
        <li id="NODE16">Test</li>
      </conbody>
    </concept>
    <concept>
      <title></title>
      <conbody>
        <p>Para after r4</p>
        <note>Para after r4</note>
      </conbody>
    </concept>
    <concept id="PROT">
      <title id="NODE17">Protocol</title>
      <conbody id="PROT">
        <p>Test</p>
        <note>Test note</note>
      </conbody>
      <concept id="NODE19">
        <title id="NODE20">General information</title>
        <conbody id="NODE19">
          <note>Test note.</note>
        </conbody>
      </concept>
      <concept>
        <title></title>
        <conbody>
          <p>Para after r5</p>
          <note>Para after r5</note>
        </conbody>
      </concept>
    </concept>
  </concept>
</concept>
```

Comment: Your xml is not well-formed.

Comment: It is well formed xml structure, I have used this xml for transformation.

Comment: I suggest you validate your xml first.

Comment: Thanks, I have validated the XML, there was one error which I fixed it.

Comment: Please help me with the solution

Comment: You expected output is not valid xml. Furthermore there is a value NODE37, where does that value come from? Please be more precise in asking a question. In this current state we have to guess too much.

Comment: @ak2103 You should really double check that your XML is well formed, especially if users here tell you that it isn't. And you should format your code, so it is easier to read (that way you would have found out that it is not well formed)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have corrected my expected output as well as I have received the comments. Hereafter I will try to keep the xml very simple. Please check now, If it is feasible for you folks to provide a solution to this problem. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a good start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Start with match on root, and send control to design-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xml/body/design"/> 
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="design">
    <concept>
      <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" select="'urn:ptc:names:arbortext:dita:xsd:techinfo.xsd'"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/xml/frontm/prolog"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[matches(local-name(),'r[0-9]')]"/> 
    </concept>           
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="prolog">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    <shortdesc/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <critdates>
      <revised modified="{@year}-{@month}"/>      
    </critdates>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <!--Match on all nodes like r1, r2,r4,r5,r6 etc-->
  <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(),'r[0-9]')]">
    <concept>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rtit"/>    
      <conbody>
        <!-- the logic of @id/@group attributes is not clear -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(starts-with(local-name(),'r')) ]"/>    
      </conbody>
      <!-- apply recursive -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[matches(local-name(),'r[0-9]')]"/> 
    </concept>           
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rtit">
    <title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </title>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the given source this will be the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<concept xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:ptc:names:arbortext:dita:xsd:techinfo.xsd"
         id="NODE11">
   <title id="NODE2">Door</title>
   <shortdesc/>
   <prolog>
      <critdates>
         <revised modified="09-9"/>
      </critdates>
   </prolog>
   <concept id="NODE37">
      <title id="NODE38">Door</title>
      <conbody>
         <p>Para after r4</p>
         <note>Para after r4</note>
      </conbody>
      <concept id="ALLM">
         <title id="NODE14">General</title>
         <conbody>
            <p>
               <hp2>Test:</hp2>
            </p>
            <list style="random">
               <li id="NODE15">Test li.</li>
               <li id="NODE16">Test</li>
            </list>
            <note>Failure </note>
         </conbody>
      </concept>
      <concept id="PROT">
         <title id="NODE17">Protocol</title>
         <conbody>
            <p>Test</p>
            <note>Test note</note>
            <p>Para after r5</p>
            <note>Para after r5</note>
         </conbody>
         <concept id="NODE19">
            <title id="NODE20">General information</title>
            <conbody>
               <note>Test note.</note>
            </conbody>
         </concept>
      </concept>
   </concept>
</concept>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, It just that the output is slightly deviated, For ex - "<p>Para after r5</p><note>Para after r5</note>", should have come inside NODE19 or content should should be with new concept with conbody inside as following sibling at r5 level, However the content is fetched inside PROT, which is basically r4 that's not matching the requirement. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the approach gives you some direction to try yourself?

Comment: This approach will definitely help me to solve further  problems. Thanks you so much.

Comment: I need one more help, how to handle the same scenario if the node is like proc, r4sproc, r5sproc....r8sproc?  currently the node is sequential like r3, r4, r5....r8 therefore it is simple. Please guide on the same.

Comment: <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(),'r[0-9]sproc')]">

Comment: Thanks, How to match proc and r4sproc, r5sproc....r8sproc

Comment: Do I need to match proc node seperately?

Comment: Structure will be like <proc>  <procl> r4sproc, r5sproc....r8sproc etc </procl> </proc>.

Comment: Maybe better to ask new question,
`<xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(),'r[0-9]?s?procl?')]">`

Comment: Thanks, If it does not work...I will ask a new question